Does the standard form of a linear program have inequality or equality constrtains?
First off, I know that both are equivalent up to slack variables.
I used to think that the canonical form had the constraint as $Ax = b$, and the standard form had them as $Ax \leq b$ (this is for example the terminology of Vanderbei's "Linear Programming").
But there are many contradictions in textobooks; for example the wikipedia Simplex page or Luenberger's "Linear and nonlienar programming", section 2.1, say that the standard form uses $Ax = b$, while the Linear programming one says that standard form is $Ax \leq b$.
Is there simply no consensus?

The reason for the different standard formulations is in-part to what the end-goal of the author is trying to convey, or the problem formulation at hand. For example, one may say
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max & z=c^Tx\\
s.t. & Ax\le b\\
&x\ge0
\end{array}
$$
to be the standard canonical form, as any constraint with $\ge$ or $=$ can be converted into a $\le$ constraint. Hence, many authors may say that this is a standard formulation as from here we can advance onto the
what is the universally understood standard form
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max & z=c^Tx\\
s.t. & Ax= b\\
&x\ge0
\end{array}
$$
with the difference being the slack variables. Thus, Vanderbei's interpretation of standard form is just as valid as the Wikipedia definition since they only differ from these slack variables, and it can just be seen as a "step-behind" in the problem formulation.
